# How to change cell reference style in Excel Online?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know how to change cell reference style (`A1` or `R1C1`) in Excel for Windows.

But I have not found how to change that in Excel Online.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R1C1 reference style feature seems to have been unavailable in the Web Apps (Excel online) version. And it still be not supported now. I think we should feedback this to Microsoft.

This question was previously asked by others in the Microsoft Community. Review [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/does-the-online-app-for-excel-support-the-r1c1/4c575080-45f7-431c-962f-bbec3b996796?auth=1).